# Authenticate against AD LDS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, active-directory

I've just installed AD LDS on my developer PC and everything works find, I've even created the user "abc" via ADSI Edit.

My goal is to test my ASP.NET Mvc 3 web application with my test AD LDS instance.

How can I get the app to authenticate the user against the instance? Do I have to write a custom membership provider? (overriding some stuff in the default AD membership provider?)

Thank you for any help!

Comment: You shouldn't need to write a custom provider. Can you connect to it using any other LDAP tool?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do any authentication since it is handled by iis.
All you have to do is change authentication mode to windows.

```
   <system.web>
      <authentication mode="Windows" />
   </system.web>
```

Remember to either install iis **after** you installed AD, or register it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using AD LDS I don't think authentication mode "Windows" will be so helpful. I believe you need to create a Login View(here /Account/Logon) and use authentication mode "Forms".

Enter the followwing in web.config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".ADAuthCookie" loginUrl="~/Account/Logon" timeout="30" slidingExpiration="false" protection="All"/>
</authentication>

<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

Authenticating the user can be accomplished by using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement. The controller code should look something like this:

```
public ActionResult Logon(LogonModel model)
{
    if (model.Username != null && model.Password != null)
    {

        string container = "CN=...,DC=....,DC=...."; //Your container in LDS 
        string ldapserver = "server:port"; //LDS server

        PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(
            ContextType.ApplicationDirectory, 
            ldapserver, 
            container, 
            ContextOptions.SimpleBind);


        bool authenticate = context.ValidateCredentials(string.Format("CN={0},{1}", model.Username, container), model.Password, ContextOptions.SimpleBind);

        if (authenticate)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(model.Username, false);
        }
        else
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            this.ModelState.AddModelError("Password", "Wrong username or password");
        }
    }

    return View("Logon", new LogonModel { Username = model.Username });
}
```

Note that this ONLY solves authentication and not authorization.

You can also use membership providers, but if you are looking for an easy solution I think this should do the trick.